# Camel isn't propagating exceptions when they are thrown inside of a multicast when the route is transacted

Tags: apache-camel

I have a usecase where i have to multicast the input to multiple routes.
I do this by using apache camel's multicast component.
If there are any exception i handle it using Exception clause.
I have also marked the route to not handle the error by marking it as shown below

```
<camel:route errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler">
        <camel:from uri="direct://SequenceFlow_5"/>
        <camel:transacted ref="sapdatastoretransacted"/>
        <camel:setBody id="CallActivity_3_1477551532659">
            <camel:simple>${in.body}+2</camel:simple>
        </camel:setBody>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="Branch B" id="CallActivity_10_1477551532662">
            <camel:constant>236</camel:constant>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:log message="End of multicast branch encountered" loggingLevel="INFO" id="EndEvent_1_1477551532665"/>
    </camel:route>
```

when the route is marked as "noErrorHandler" any error from the route is thrown back to caller.
In my use case this works perfectly, when the route is non transactional.
But when the route is transactional the error is not thrown to the caller in case of multicast.

What i want to achieve is to handle error from subroutes created by multicast and handle the error from the route which invoked the multicast.